# What does str in ls.str( ) stand for?

Tags: r

In r language, what is the meaning of "str" in "ls.str()"? I understand that ls.str() gives you a detailed description of the objects in the active memory. But I am still confused about what str stands for then?

Answer (score 6):

From `?ls.str`:

> ‘ls.str’ and ‘lsf.str’ are variations of ‘ls’ applying ‘str()’

From `?str`:

> Compactly display the internal *str*ucture of an R object ...

so the answer is "list structures".

Answer (score 2):

Taken from the [Full reference manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/fullrefman.pdf).

**str**
Compactly Display the Structure of an Arbitrary R Object

*Description*
Compactly display the internal
str
ucture of an
R
object, a diagnostic function and an alternative to
summary
(and to some extent,
dput
). Ideally, only one line for each ‘basic’ structure is displayed. It
is especially well suited to compactly display the (abbreviated) contents of (possibly nested) lists.
The idea is to give reasonable output for
any
R
object. It calls
args
for (non-primitive) function
objects.
strOptions()
is a convenience function for setting
options
(str = .)
, see the examples.

Answer (score 1):

The abbreviation "str" is taken from the first 3 letters of the word **str**ucture. 
[The same is highlighted in the official R documentation below]

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.5.1/topics/str